# How to add column comments to the hive table which is using row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am trying to add column comments to the hive table (cities_v2) which is using `org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde`. When I trigger the alter query to add column comment, it is running fine without error but still the column comment remains "from deserializer". Please help me.

Queries used to alter the table to add comments:

```
alter table cities_v2  change city_id city_id string COMMENT 'Unique ID from DCM';
alter table cities_v2  change city city string COMMENT 'City name, in English';
```

create table query:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cities_v2 (
city_id             INT ,
city                STRING
)
PARTITIONED BY (filedate_pst STRING)
row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
with serdeproperties(
"separatorChar" = "\," ,
"quoteChar" = "\"")
LOCATION '/common/data/dfa/cities_v2/'
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```